# SQL query with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgresql and wondering if I can do this in one request:
I have a table with four columns: id, start, end and user_id
In one request, I do a

```
SELECT sum(finish - start) as duration, user_id group by user_id
```

Now it would be great if I kept somewhere the ids of the fetched rows too because I need them later in the code
Is this possible at all?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [Window Functions and Partitions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) or perhaps `array_agg`.

Assuming this example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER,
    start INTEGER,
    finish INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO mytable(id, user_id, start, finish) VALUES (1, 1, 5, 10);  -- duration: 5
INSERT INTO mytable(id, user_id, start, finish) VALUES (2, 2, 10, 30); -- duration: 20
INSERT INTO mytable(id, user_id, start, finish) VALUES (3, 1, 15, 20); -- duration: 5
```

As you know, `SELECT SUM(finish - start), user_id FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id` will return:

```
10  | 1
20  | 2
```

I presume what you don't want is the output of this query (since you might as well not use aggregates if you use a column with a unique non-null constraint in your `GROUP BY`, as I presume `id` is): `SELECT id, SUM(finish - start), user_id FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id, id`.

Using a window function, you can used data from other rows related to the current row.

The following query:

```
SELECT id, SUM(finish - start) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS duration, user_id
    FROM mytable ORDER BY user_id
```

produces these results:

```
1 | 10 | 1
3 | 10 | 1
2 | 20 | 2
```

You'll now get a row per `id` used, but the `SUM` applies to the entire set of rows within the window frame (here, all those with the same `user_id` as the current row).

As far as your application is concerned, you would probably then need to read the rows one by one and store the relevant values of `id` somewhere until `user_id` changes.

Alternatively, you could use [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) to aggregate all the IDs into an array:

```
SELECT array_agg(id), SUM(finish - start) AS duration, user_id
    FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_id, duration


{1, 3}  | 10 | 1
{2}     | 20 | 2
```

If, for example, you want this in a space-separated string, use [`array_to_string`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) on top of this:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(id), ' '), SUM(finish - start) AS duration, user_id
    FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_id, duration
```

Comment: @PomponVdp: This seems to be the solution to your question. So would you please up-vote the answer (if you didn't already) and accept the answer as the best solution to your question. To do so click the V under the vote counter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string as result (not an array), then you can simplify the task with [**`string_agg()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) in PostgreSQL **9.0 or later**:

```
SELECT user_id
     , sum(finish - start) AS duration
     , string_agg(id, ', ') AS ids
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` is the row id, have you tried this?

```
SELECT id, sum(finish - start) as duration, user_id group by id, user_id
```